# .htaccess redirect all requests to index.php even if the requested file exists

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm writing my first **.htaccess** file. I would like to know how to rewrite `localhost/home/user/` to `localhost/index.php?home&id=user` even if the '`home`' directory exists.

Is this possible?

Comment: Don't you mean it the other way around? Like from localhost/home/user to localhost/index.php?home&id=user? Otherwise you can simply do that using PHP

Comment: sry... yes i meant that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad practice doing that, however, if you really want this the lines you need are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#(things you want to do beforehand)

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule !^http://localhost/index.php?home&id=user [R,L]
#(things you want to do after redirect)
```

(you may need `$1` instead of 'user', depending on security you use; and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` from PHP if using .htpasswd from Apache)
You can add different flags of course, the RewriteRule Flags doc is [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html).

Comment: You're welcome (love me with a +1 too, not only marking my answer as the solution please! :P)